# Drawing multiple related objects in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I wish to draw a basic robotic arm using OpenGL using primitive shapes such as cylinders, cubes etc.

At this point, I managed to draw the arm statically by applying the necessary transformations viz. translation, rotation, scaling etc.

I now need to make it interactive. That is, when a user selects a certain object and moves it around, smaller objects attached to it must move.

Example:- If the arm is being moved by the user, the wrist, the palm and the fingers must move but not the shoulder. Likewise if the palm is selected and rotated about the wrist, only the fingers attached to that palm may move along with the palm, not the arm or the wrist.

What kind of design pattern must I follow in my code to achieve this cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is called a transformation hierachy and is in fact covered by the chapter on transformations in the OpenGL-1.1 programming guide (recent versions of OpenGL, namely v3 and later largeley stripped down the matrix manipulation stuff, so you need to implement this yourself, but the principle remains the same).

Look toward the end of this chapter (I suggest you read the whole thing):

http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter03.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist, but I think you should consider using a toolkit on top of OpenGL. Maybe something like OpenSceneGraph ( http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/About/Introduction )

Look at an introduction to it here : http://www.artoolworks.com/support/library/An_Introduction_to_OpenSceneGraph_and_osgART

It explains that you can build "trees of objects" that will be linked.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with them myself, but I do know that OpenGL keeps track of transformation matrices on a stack.

This would seem to allow you to push one transformation matrix to draw the parent objects (say, the upper arm) and then sequentially push and pop transformation matrices for each child object of the arm, using the hierarchical relationship of its components. The transformations are applied in sequence for each matrix currently on the stack, so you only have to apply the transformation for each parent object once, and then all children are drawn relative to its position.

Check out this page for more details (I haven't read it myself!):

http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter03.html

Does that help? It seems applicable for simple cases like what you describe. For more complex applications, Pascal T. is right that you may want to look at layers on top of OpenGL.